# Having Issue on jQuery Mousemove To Left and Right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/tw0uapLk/2/) and let me know how I can change the 
use of the `.css()` rule of `background-position-x` event ONLY when the mouse is moving to Left or Right on the `.homeSlide` ? what is happening now is As soon as the mouse enters into the `.homeSlide` jquery is running the CSS rule but I want to do it only when the mouse is moving

```js
jQuery('.homeSlider').mousemove(function(move){
    var moveMouse = (move.pageX * -1 / 3);
    jQuery('.homeSlider .slide').css({
        'background-position-x': moveMouse + 'px'
    });
});

jQuery('.homeSlider').mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('.homeSlider .slide').animate({
        'background-position-x': '0'
    });
});
```

```css
.homeSlider {width: 100%; height: 400px; background: red;}
.homeSlider .slide {width:100%; height: 100%; background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-JHKDpZ5orFc/T0523m_rAlI/AAAAAAAAAEU/zYZv__hk74I/s1600/Panorama_by_erikcollinder.jpeg) 0 0;}
.slide {transition: background-position-x 0.5s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homeSlider">
    <div class="slide"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when mouse enters the image element, it already has some x position, so the image moves by x. So we need to decide a starting point for x position. 
Try this code:

```
var startingPos = 0;

jQuery('.homeSlider').mousemove(function(move){
    var moveMouse = (move.pageX * -1 / 3);
    if(startingPos == 0){
        startingPos = moveMouse;
        return;
    } else {
        moveMouse = moveMouse-startingPos;
    }
    jQuery('.homeSlider .slide').css({
        'background-position-x': moveMouse + 'px'
    });
});

jQuery('.homeSlider').mouseleave(function(){
    startingPos = 0;
    jQuery('.homeSlider .slide').animate({
        'background-position-x': '0'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `background-position-x 0.5s` to `background-position-x 0.0s`. Check
this
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw0uapLk/6/) which is a combination with the other answer [user3580410](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580410/user3580410) provides

Answer (score 0):

Try and put on the left and right side an "<" or ">" image href on them make a hover action that will modify the position of the picture the way you want it to react.
Here is an example:
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthImageSlider/